# Using linux command line, what is the easiest way to delete matching files in all subdirectories of other extensions?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I've been browsing around and trying to find the answer - bonus points for doing this in the shortest number of characters.

So I have file1.ex1 file2.ex1 file1.ex2 but no file2.ex2

I want to delete all the ex1 files, but only if ex2 version exists first.

So I assume this means I need to get a directory listing of all files ending in the extension I want to keep, piping that through and searching for which ones match the first part of the filename, then piping that into a delete command.

I want to use standard linux fu as I'm doing this on unraid.

I know this is easy for most of you, which is why I added to do it in least number of characters for a challenge!  Oh, and this should work in all subdirectories matching to whatever is in that subdirectory only.

Thanks!

Marshalleq

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name "*.ex1" -type f -exec sh -c '[ -f "${1%1}2" ] && echo rm "$1"' sh {} \;
```

This finds all regular files with suffix `.ex1` recursively in the current directory and executes the shell script inside 
of the single quotes for each file (`$1`) found. It only prints the `rm` command it would execute.

- `[ -f "${1%1}2" ] &&` tests if argument `$1` exists with `2` as last character. 
  `${1%1}` removes the last `1` and we replace it with `2`. The `[ -f ... ] &&` tests if the file exists and executes the following command if the condition is true.

You can remove the `echo` and run the command again to really delete the files.

If you want to delete the files only in the current directory and not its subdirectories:

```
for i in *.ex1; do [ -f "${i%1}2" ] && echo rm "$i"; done
```

Again, you have to remove the `echo` to execute `rm`.

Comment: Nice!  Trying it out now.  Thankyou!

Comment: So because files called ex1 and ex2 are examples only, if I wanted to delete all files that are *.doc with *.odt but only where *.odt exists, the following would be correct?  find . -name "*.doc" -type f -exec sh -c '[ -f "${doc%1}odt" ] && echo rm "$1"' sh {} \;

Comment: If you want to delete `.doc` files where an `.odt` file exists, change `*.ex1` to `*.doc` and `${1%1}2` to `${1%doc}odt` (or `${i%1}2` to `${i%doc}odt`). And don't forget to remove the `echo` if the output looks okay.

Comment: Tried the multi-folder version on a single folder and that works!  Thankyou, will try it on a nested folder once I've copied across the duplicates (as odd as that sounds).  Thanks, you're a genius!